# database: associate facebook account with your website account

Tags: database, facebook, integration, structure, account

Many websites have integrated with Facebook. After signing up with Facebook account, website asks to create website account e.g: pinterest.

I'm wondering how do the two account associate with each other in the database (i.e which attribute can connect them?).

Comment: Facebook has a great tutorial on this on their [developers page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/). I advice you to read it.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to application developer to decide how application/site account is linked to the Facebook account but mostly it's done by using Facebook User `id` which is the only unique identifier provided by Facebook after user connected with application.

Comment: hey, juicy, thank you for your reply. Since i'll use two table to store facebook info and web account info separately, and user signup with facebook first. So should i fetch the facebook user id and then store the id in the other table as my websites user id?

Comment: You can't really fetch it without knowing it ;) It'll be passed to your application within [`signed_request`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) once user authorized your app. Get familiar with [authentication guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) to know more about those aspects

Comment: Hey juicy, thanks for the info. I've gone through all the parts you mentioned.i.e user authorization. So far, my websites could get user data after user permission. i just stucked at the database structure 'cause i'm not sure how to link the user info in these two tables :)

Comment: You can either link em by table foreign key or by Facebook user id, one of those will appear in both tables